# How much of a surface mount PIN diode is semiconductor?

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, semiconductors

The problem: manufacturers provide a lot of information on the operation and characteristics of the devices, but not on what's inside.

I'm trying to incorporate the effects of a surface mount PIN diode in a full wave electromagnetic simulation. The only problem is that there is a portion of doped and undoped silicon in the diode, only I don't know how much.

It's apparent that the pads on the device packaging will likely dominate the interactions due to the diode, but the simulation is for a sensitive device so if possible I'd like to include all electrically active components.

Are there any experts out there who know roughly how much of these surface mount devices are doped / undoped semiconductor compared to the packaging? (the specific diode in this case is the SOD-882 from the SMP 1322 series, Skyworks)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with your simulation? What signal frequencies are involved?

Comment: If this is for legitimate student research you should approach the manufacturer directly. They are very often supportive of student research and study programs. Most other folks here are going to have access to the same info you can find in the data sheets,

Comment: If you really just need the proportion of different materials, call the vendor and request a materials declaration. This will give the weight percentage of each different material in the product.

Comment: In technical documentation for that part, they have package S-parameters and circuit models. That will do for most simulations. Big undoped semiconductor areas will look like lossy parasitic capacitance, doped semiconductor between connections and active regions will just add to series resistance. It's only if you are doing a full 3D FEM at THz frequencies that you'd need physical detail of the layout.